# Returning JSON data out of the callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Is it possible to return the msg variable in javascript below out of the callback function?   I tried doing this, but got a null, even though the msg variable had data in it while in the scope of the callback function.

```
var msg = load();


function load()
{
     $.ajax({  
     type: "POST",  
     url: "myPage.aspx/MyMethod",  
     data: jsonText,  
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
     dataType: "json",  
     success: function (msg) { return msg;  // Doesn't return anything because
                                            //it's automatically called on success??? 
     },  
     failure: function () { alert("Failure"); }  
     }); 
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return "success:" method's data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753844/return-success-methods-data)

Comment: @Quentin: That question is actually a duplicate as well (and its accepted answer is quite poor), of [this other one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success) that has much better answers (although still none demonstrating both a callback and, separately, a synchronous request).

Answer (score 3):

Not with an asynchronous request, which is the normal kind of ajax request and the preferred kind. That's because `load` returns before you get your reply from the server, so obviously it can't return the `msg`. Instead, have `load` accept a callback:

```
load(function(msg) {
    // Use msg here
});

function load(callback)
{
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "myPage.aspx/MyMethod",  
        data: jsonText,  
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
        dataType: "json",  
        success: function (msg) {
            // Call our callback with the message
            callback(msg);
        },  
        failure: function () {
            // Call our callback with an indication things failed
            callback(null); // Or however you want to flag failure
        }
     }); 
}
```

If **absolutely unavoidable**, you could use a synchronous request by setting `async: false` in your [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) options (that's a link to the docs), then do it like this:

```
var msg = load();

function load(callback)
{
    var result;
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "myPage.aspx/MyMethod",  
        data: jsonText,  
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
        dataType: "json",  
        async: false,
        success: function (msg) {
            // Set the `result` value here. We can't *return* it
            // here because, of course, that would just return it
            // from our `success` function.
            result = msg;
        },  
        failure: function () {
            result = null; // Or however you want to flag failure
        }
     });

     // Because we've made the request synchronous, we won't get here
     // until the ajax call is complete and `result` has been set by
     // the callbacks above; we can now return it.
     return result;
}
```

But ***synchronous*** requests make for a poor user experience and, moreover, are almost never necessary, so should be avoided as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to pass a callback to `load()` because the XHR is asynchronous.

BTW, `msg` should contain `undefined` if you don't explicitly return anything.